# access_log off for a 301 or a 302

Tags: nginx, logging, haproxy

I am using haproxy and nginx. Haproxy has sthis option to check health of my backends:

```
option httpchk HEAD /lol.txt HTTP/1.0
```

All works fine, but I do not want to log this health check

So in my nginx configuration I add:

```
    location /lol.txt {
    access_log off;
    }
```

The problem is, this location returns a 301, so I got these logs again and again:

```
 10.1.29.1 - - [15/Mar/2013:06:51:36 +0100] "HEAD /lol.txt HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "-" "-"
```

Have you some idea to have the access_log off working?

Regards.

Comment: There's no `rewrite` directive in that location block, so it can't be being used. Please provide the rest of your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some other location that handles the request, and your `access_log` doesn't apply, or maybe it gets overwritten by another `access_log` directive.

Try the following if you want to disable passing these requests to the backend:

```
location = /lol.txt {
    access_log off;
    return 'It works!' 200;
}
```

Or, alternatively, if you still must pass the request to be backend:

```
if ($request_uri = /lol.txt) {
    access_log off;
}
```

It might also help to try to make sure that these `access_log off` appear after any other `access_log` directives, e.g. see if moving it around makes a difference.

Hope it helps, and please report what worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude `3xx` status from being log using `map` like

```
map $status $log {
    default     1;
    ~^[3]       0;
}
```

Then change `access_log` to :

```
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$log;
```

NGINX Documentation [Enabling Conditional Logging](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#enabling-conditional-logging)

Comment: or use it more simple like `map $status $log {default 1;301 0;302 0;}`